# laravel4 routes works with route /, but does not for other routes

Tags: php, laravel-4

I set up a laravel4 project, but the route only works for the route /.

I also set up a vhost for the project, vhost points to laravel4/public

I have the following code in routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function()
  {
      return View::make('home');
  });

  Route::get('help', function() {
      return "asdfsafas";
  });
```

when i go to /, it shows correctly. but if i go to /help, it shows The requested URL /help was not found on this server.

Comment: oh, I forget add index.php :(                                         after i type xxxx.dev/index.php/help, it works. But how can i make it work if only typed xxxx.dev/help?

Comment: What you've got should work fine - what are you using as a http server, apache?

Try it with 'php artisan serve' in your laravel root directory.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have apache-rewrite module enabled. Most probably it will be installed on your system but not enabled. You can enable it like this from terminal.

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Then, restart apache using the following command:

`sudo service apache2 restart`

This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `DocumentRoot` to

```
laravel4/public/index.php
```

and restart Apache. Then you can access routes like

```
/help
```

instead of index.php/help